# 2 divs, adapt the top one maintaining the bottom fixed height

Tags: layout, css

I searched all around stackoverflow but I couldn't find an answer for it. Here is the problem:

I have two divs, one on top of the other. I want to have the top div to adapt the height depending on the height of the below div.

```
<div id="parent" style="height:300px">
   <div id="div1" style="height:auto"></div>
   <div id="div2" style="height:45px"></div>
</div>
```

This because I intend to show/hide the bottom div and the top div must resize to fill the parent div.

I forgot to mention that the first div (the one that needs to adapt) has long content with overflow:scroll

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you can **display:table** property. Write like this:

```
#parent{
 display:table;
 height:300px;
 width:100%;
}
#parent > div{
    display:table-row;
}
#div1{
    background:red;
}
#div2{
    background:green;
    height:45px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7NuFr/

Comment: I tried that already but as I mentioned the top div will contain long paragraphs. With overlfow hidden and fixed height, the top div will always scale and it won't keep the parent heigth.

See http://jsfiddle.net/7NuFr/6/